# i am not able to place a button on broadleaf admin part?

Tags: broadleaf-commerce

I am using broadleaf.

I am not able to add a button on admin part.

As of now my requirement is order cancel or return two functionality there.

These two are comes in admin customer care part.when i am click on individual order gird how can i add buttons based on status of order?

I need How to Add buttons and how to change functionality of admin.

But i did not found any code for adding or extending functionality i need a leaf broadleaf guys

i want poc please?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you need to add a Entity form like

`EntityForm form = (EntityForm) model.asMap().get("entityForm");`

then you need to EntityFormAction like

```
EntityFormAction efa = new EntityFormAction(EntityFormAction.ADD)
.withDisplayText("Invoice").withIconClass("icon-print")
.withButtonClass("invoice-button").withUrlPostfix("/invoice");
```

then write

`form.addAction(efa);`